# IF rule on a checkbox field, but the condition is on the Contact field

Tags: contact, opportunitycontactrole

Here's the dilemma,

I have a few contacts related to each opportunity. Each contact has their own Contact Role, let's say Sales, Tech, and Product.

I have a checkbox field for Sales, Tech, and Product, and the idea is to have this checkbox auto-filled if we have at least one contact with the Contact Role of "Sales", "Tech", or "Product" respectively.

I understand how to use the IF function on the checkbox, but I can't seem to find the field Contact Role anywhere.

How does one figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Sales, Tech, and Product check box fields are available in Opportunity object?

Comment: Yes, checkbox fields in the Opportunity object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a trigger on OpportunityContactRole object.

Try with below code and its working in my demo org.

Replace the field API names ( Sales, Tech & Product) as per your org.

```
trigger OppcontactRole on OpportunityContactRole (after insert,after update) {


set<id> oppids = new set<id>();
map<id,string> conrolemap = new map<id,string>();
If(trigger.Isafter && (trigger.Isinsert ||trigger.Isupdate)){
    
    for(OpportunityContactRole ocr: trigger.new){
        
        If(ocr.opportunityid !=Null ){
           oppids.add(ocr.opportunityid) ;
           conrolemap.put(ocr.opportunityid, ocr.Role);
        }
        
    }
}

Map<id,opportunity> mapopproleupdate = new map<id,opportunity>([select id,Sales__c,Tech__c,Product__C from opportunity where id=:oppids ]);

 for(OpportunityContactRole ocr: trigger.new){
     
     for(opportunity opp : mapopproleupdate.values()){
         
         if(opp.id == ocr.OpportunityId ){
             
             if(ocr.Role == 'Sales'){
                 opp.Sales__c = true;
             }else if(ocr.Role == 'Tech'){
                 opp.Tech__c = true;
             }else if(ocr.Role == 'Product'){
                 opp.Product__c = true;
             }
         }
         
     }
 }

Update mapopproleupdate.values();
```

}